Update observable object ONLY when clicking the save button MVVM
I have an observable object called "Customer" that I only want to update when I click the save button. However, the issue arises if i modified any property of this object without clicking the save button, as it gets updated automatically. I notice this when I return to the edit page after navigating away without clicking the save button— the object retains the modified values.
View:
    <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="5">
    <Frame BackgroundColor="Transparent" BorderColor="DodgerBlue" Padding="5" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" CornerRadius="30" >
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="5">
            <Entry  Text="{Binding Customer.customerID}" x:Name="customerIDTxt"  Placeholder="رقم الهوية" PlaceholderColor="LightGray" TextColor="Black" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="0,0,20,0" />
        </StackLayout>
    </Frame>
</StackLayout>
.
.
.
<StackLayout Grid.Row="7" Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="5">
    <Frame BackgroundColor="Transparent" BorderColor="DodgerBlue" Padding="5" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" CornerRadius="30" >
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="5">
            <Editor Text="{Binding Customer.notes}"  PlaceholderColor="Black" TextColor="Black" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="0,0,20,0" AutoSize="TextChanges" MaxLength="180" />
        </StackLayout>
    </Frame>
</StackLayout>

               <Button Text="حفظ" HorizontalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="200" Margin="8"Style="{StaticResource ButtonOutline}" Command="{Binding EditCustomerCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Customer}"/>

ViewModel:
[QueryProperty(nameof(Customer), "Customer")]
public partial class CustomerDetailsEditViewModel : BaseViewModel
{

     [ObservableProperty]
     public Customer customer;
    
    
        [RelayCommand]
        public async Task EditCustomer(Customer customer)
        {
          // Update logic in here...
        }

}




make a copy of the object and bind to it, or bind to a temporary property

@Jason, attempting to copy to a temporary object didn't resolve the issue; the changes were still being saved somewhere even if I navigated away and returned to the edit page. As for using a temporary property, I haven't tried it because I believe it's not a suitable approach, especially if the object has many properties.

you have to create a copy of the object, not just create another reference to it.  And this is why MVVM has both a Model and a ViewModel, so you can separate them

Sorry i didn't catch your answer, how can i bind to an object that its not Observable

the copy can be Observable too.  Although if you are only allowing the user to make edits via the UI, it's probably not important that it is.

Cloning the observable object and binding to it did the trick, although I'm uncertain if this is the optimal solution

Hi @Json, how can i return the updated object to the previous view if i used popAsync when clicking the save button?

if you passed a reference to an object both views will point to the same copy


how can i return the updated object to the previous view if i used
popAsync when clicking the save button

There are several ways to achieve this.
Method 1:A common approach is to use EventHandler.
You can define EventHandler in this view(Suppose the name is SelectedPage), just as follows:
 public static EventHandler<Item> mEventHandler; // define a static  EventHandler

After you select an item, you can pass the selected item with the following code:
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler<Item> handler = mEventHandler;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            Item item = new Item { Name= "Hello." };

            mEventHandler(this, item);
        }

        Navigation.PopAsync();
    }

In the previous page, you can add the following code in the constructor of YourPreviousPage :
        SelectedPage.mEventHandler += delegate (object s, Item a)
        {
            BackCall(s, a);
        };

And the code of function BackCall is:
 private void BackCall(object send, Item a)
    {
        if (a == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(a));
        }
        else {

             DisplayAlert("Alert", "call back value is : " + a.Name, "OK");
        }
    }

method 2
You can also use Messenger to achieve this function.
Please refer to the following code:
// Create a message
public class LoggedInUserChangedMessage : ValueChangedMessage<User>
{
    public LoggedInUserChangedMessage(User user) : base(user)
    {        
    }
}

// Register a message in some module
WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Register<LoggedInUserChangedMessage>(this, (r, m) =>
{
    // Handle the message here, with r being the recipient and m being the
    // input message. Using the recipient passed as input makes it so that
    // the lambda expression doesn't capture "this", improving performance.
});

// Send a message from some other module
WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Send(new LoggedInUserChangedMessage(user));


I used Method 1 and it worked, Thanks
